# Android WebView not Loading InstantStreetView.com

Tags: android, webview

This is my Complete Code. And the page does not load. Why?

```
package com.test.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      mWebView.loadUrl("http://instantstreetview.com");
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
        {
                if( url.toLowerCase().contains("instantstreetview.com")) {
                  //  mWebView.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }
          //  Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  android.net.Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
                return true;


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    { //if back key is pressed
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

'''''''''''''''
And this is the manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.webview" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But the page doesn't load. Any other page works. This page works in the chrome browser. What more do i need to add?

Comment: add these lines alsomay be worked    `public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {             
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
         }` and use this url `http://www.instantstreetview.com`

Comment: Its loading the urls. Just this one isnt loading.

Comment: Is there a different site where such type of questions are answered?

Comment: I checked with your url in webview its working fine

Comment: I updated my question with the complete code. Does it work by you?

Comment: i run your code its working fine. May be some issue with your device  or emulator where you running the code.

Comment: Tried in the Nexus emulator and on a physical LG G3. When you ran the code did you see the street view?